How to checked a switch in a repeater outside the repeater?
I'm not a developer, I'm just starting out (20 days) so I don't understand everything and I probably make a lot of mistakes
I'm trying to create a plasmoid for KDE Plasma 6 that has the function of launching scripts/applications via dynamically generated toggle switches.
The toggleswitches are generated dynamically and they run their own scripts, it works.
The problem I can't seem to resolve is that I added an option that has the function of leaving the toggle switch in its true position when a script ends with exit 1 and when the script goes to exit 1. exit 0, the toggle switch should change from true to false. . .
For example, here is a script:
"dolphin; exit 1"
I click the toggle switch -> it becomes true -> the Dolphin application launches -> the toggle switch stays true as long as Dolphin is open -> I close Dolphin -> the toggle switch should return to false position but the problem is that it does not return to false position
In main.qml the part of Plasma5Support.DataSource that says to bring back the toggleswitch "switchItem.checked = checked;" doesn't move the toggleswitch, how can I do that?
config.qml:
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls as QQC2
import QtQml.Models
import org.kde.plasma.plasmoid
import org.kde.kcmutils as KCM
import org.kde.kirigami as Kirigami

KCM.ScrollViewKCM {
   id: root
   property alias switchModel: switchModel

   property string cfg_switches

   property string cfg_statusScriptEnabled: statusScriptEnabledBox.checked

   
   onVisibleChanged: {
       if (!visible)
           switchModel.save();
   }

   ListModel {
       id: switchModel

       Component.onCompleted: { switchModel.loadString(root.cfg_switches); }

       function loadString(string) {
           clear();
           let switches = JSON.parse(string);
           switches.forEach(function(switchis) {
               addSwitch(switchis.name, switchis.switchId, switchis.isMaster, switchis.isMain, switchis.checked, switchis.defaultPosition, switchis.onScriptEnabled, switchis.offScriptEnabled, switchis.onScript, switchis.offScript, switchis.statusScriptEnabled, switchis.statusScript, switchis.runStatusOnStart, switchis.updateInterval, switchis.updateIntervalUnitl, switchis.interval);
           });
       }

       function addSwitch(name, switchId, isMaster, isMain, checked, defaultPosition, onScriptEnabled, offScriptEnabled, onScript, offScript, statusScriptEnabled, statusScript, runStatusOnStart, updateInterval, updateIntervalUnitl, interval) {
           append({
               "name": name, "switchId": switchId, "isMaster": isMaster, "isMain": isMain, "checked": checked, "defaultPosition": defaultPosition, "onScriptEnabled": onScriptEnabled, "offScriptEnabled": offScriptEnabled, "onScript": onScript, "offScript": offScript,
               "statusScriptEnabled": statusScriptEnabled, "statusScript": statusScript,"runStatusOnStart": runStatusOnStart, "updateInterval": updateInterval, "updateIntervalUnitl": updateIntervalUnitl,"interval": interval});
       }

       function save() {
           var switchList = [];
           for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
               switchList.push(get(i));
           }
           root.cfg_switches = JSON.stringify(switchList);
       }

       property string roleLabel: ""

       function updateLabels() {
           for (var i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
               var switchis = get(i);
               if (switchis.isMaster)
                   setProperty(i, "roleLabel", "Master");
               else
                   setProperty(i, "roleLabel", "Main");
           }
       }

       onCountChanged: updateLabels()
   }

   header: ColumnLayout {
       spacing: Kirigami.Units.smallSpacing
   }

   view: ListView {
       id: switchView
       clip: true
       reuseItems: true
       model: switchModel

       delegate: Item {
           width: switchView.width
           implicitHeight: switchDelegate.height

           Kirigami.SwipeListItem {
               id: switchDelegate
               RowLayout {
                   height: parent.height
                   spacing: Kirigami.Units.largeSpacing

                   Kirigami.ListItemDragHandle {
                       Layout.leftMargin: Kirigami.Units.largeSpacing
                       listItem: switchDelegate
                       listView: switchView
                       onMoveRequested: (oldIndex, newIndex) => {
                           switchModel.move(oldIndex, newIndex, 1);
                           switchModel.save();
                       }
                   }
               }

               actions: [
                   Kirigami.Action {
                       text: i18n("Edit")
                       icon.name: "edit-entry-symbolic"
                       onTriggered: editSwitchSheet.openSwitch(index)
                   },
                   Kirigami.Action {
                       text: i18n("Delete")
                       icon.name: "edit-delete-remove-symbolic"
                       onTriggered: {
                           switchModel.remove(index, 1);
                           switchModel.save();
                       }
                   }
               ]

           }
       }

      
   }

   footer: RowLayout {
       spacing: Kirigami.Units.smallSpacing

       QQC2.Button {
           id: addSwitchButtonMaster
           Layout.leftMargin: Kirigami.Units.largeSpacing - 6
           text: "Add Switch Master…"
           icon.name: "list-add-symbolic"
           onClicked: {
               var switchId = "isMaster_" + new Date().getTime();
               switchModel.addSwitch("Nom du switch ici", switchId, true, false, false, false, false, false, "sleep 3; exit 0", "dolphin; exit 1", false, "/bin/status_script.sh", false, "2", "1", "120");
               switchModel.save();
           }
       }

       QQC2.Button {
           id: addSwitchButton
           Layout.leftMargin: Kirigami.Units.largeSpacing - 6
           text: "Add Switch…"
           icon.name: "list-add-symbolic"
           onClicked: {
               var switchId = "isMain_" + new Date().getTime();
               switchModel.addSwitch("Nom du switch ici", switchId,false, true, false, false, false, false, "dolphin; exit 1", "sleep 3; exit 0", false, "/bin/status_script.sh", false, "2", "1", "120");
               switchModel.save();
           }
       }

       Item {
           Layout.fillWidth: true
       }
   }

  

       onEditingSwitchChanged: {
           if (editSwitchSheet.editingSwitch) {
               switchNameField.text = editingSwitch.name;
               defaultPositionBox.checked = editingSwitch.defaultPosition;
               onScriptText.text = editingSwitch.onScript;
               offScriptText.text = editingSwitch.offScript;

           }
       }

       function openSwitch(index) {
           if (index >= 0 && index < switchModel.count) {
               editingSwitch = switchModel.get(index);
               editSwitchSheet.open();
           } else {
               editingSwitch = null;
               console.error("Invalid switch index:", index);
           }
       }
   }
}

main.qml :
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts
import QtQuick.Controls

import org.kde.plasma.plasmoid
import org.kde.plasma.core as PlasmaCore
import org.kde.plasma.components as PlasmaComponents3
import org.kde.kirigami as Kirigami
import org.kde.plasma.plasma5support as Plasma5Support

PlasmoidItem {
    id: root
    
    readonly property var switches: JSON.parse(Plasmoid.configuration.switches)
    readonly property bool hasSwitch: switches
    
    Plasma5Support.DataSource {
        id: executable
        engine: "executable"
        connectedSources: []
        
        onNewData: function(sourceName, data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < root.switches.length; ++i) {
                var switchItem = root.switches[i];
                
                if (switchItem.switchId === sourceName) {
                    switchItem.checked = data['exit code'] === 0;
                } else {
                    if (switchItem.checked && data['exit code'] !== 0) {
                        switchItem.checked = checked;
                    }
                }
            }
            
            disconnectSource(sourceName);
        }
        
        function exec(cmd) {
            connectSource(cmd);
        }
    }
    
    function toggleAction(switchId, checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < switches.length; ++i) {
            var switchItem = switches[i];
            if (switchItem.switchId === switchId) {
                if (checked) {
                    executable.exec(switchItem.onScript);
                } else {
                    executable.exec(switchItem.offScript);
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    fullRepresentation: Item {
         
            Repeater {
                model: root.switches
                delegate: PlasmaComponents3.Switch {
                    id: switchItem
                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
                    checked: modelData.defaultPosition
                    onToggled: {
                        switchItem.checked = checked;
                        root.toggleAction(modelData.switchId, switchItem.checked);
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
}



here is the Github of the plasmoid if that helps for testing the problem : https://github.com/xkain/Ultimat-ToggleSwitch

Welcome to SO. When asking questions here, it's most helpful if you can reduce the problem down to just the minimal amount of code needed to reproduce the problem. It is difficult to wade through a bunch of unrelated code to find the specific issue you want us to focus on. That's why we ask for a [mre].

Repeaters have a method called itemAt. It returns the item specified at a specific index. Does that help you with your problem?

Hi,I reduced the code and tried to clarify my problem.
The part of Plasma5Support.DataSource that says to bring back the toggleswitch "switchItem.checked = checked;" doesn't move the toggleswitch, how can I do that?
